# SQL - get top record for each date

Tags: sql-server

There is always 1 to 31 different dates which is returned in this query (depending on when in the month it is ran) and there can be multiples of the same date.
I would like to select the top 1 record for each date returned in my query.  Can someone show me how to do this?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT      
currentDate
,month(currentDate) month
,DATENAME(month, currentDate) as 'MonthName'
,DATEPART(wk,currentDate) week
,LEFT(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,currentDate) AS CHAR),4) + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(datepart (week,currentDate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) AS Yearweek
,RTMCode
,RTM
,CPCode
,CP
,CDCode
,CD
,Branded
,RV
,Holiday
FROM dbo.EDB
```

Comment: Define "top"? Is that the first entry for that given day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CROSS APPLY. Assuming CurrentDate is DATE column, here's an example. You have to change ORDER BY to either ID or CurrentDate if currentdate is datetime.

```
SELECT t2.currentDate
,month(t2.currentDate) month
,DATENAME(month, t2.currentDate) as 'MonthName'
,DATEPART(wk,t2.currentDate) week
,LEFT(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,t2.currentDate) AS CHAR),4) + 
RIGHT('0' + CAST(datepart (week,t2.currentDate) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) AS Yearweek
,RTMCode
,RTM
,CPCode
,CP
,CDCode
,CD
,Branded
,RV
,Holiday
FROM
 (SELECT currentDate
 FROM dbo.EDB e
 GROUP BY currentDate)t
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.EDB i1 
           WHERE i1.currentDate = t.CurrentDate 
           ORDER BY i1.currentDate DESC)t2
```

Comment: Ok, what you have above seems to work just fine without me changing anything.  The "currentDate" column is a date. column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you want. Is this what you want -

Sample table -

```
id  dates
2   2014-03-01
1   2014-03-01
3   2014-03-01
5   2014-03-02
6   2014-03-02
```

Query -

```
select MAX(id) as TopZ, dates
from datings 
group by dates
order by dates asc
```

Result -

```
TopZ  dates
3     2014-03-01
6     2014-03-02
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, I think you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.EDB
WHERE ID IN 
   (SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID
    FROM dbo.EDB
    WHERE MONTH(currentDate) = @month
    AND YEAR(currentDate) = @year
    GROUP BY convert(varchar, currentDate, 101))
ORDER BY currentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear how you are defining top, so max may not be flexible enough for you. I'm also assuming you have some sort of primary key on the table.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT pk
        ,ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTION BY currentDate ORDER BY [whatever]) rn
    FROM EDB
)
SELECT a.*
  FROM EDB a
       INNER JOIN
       cte b ON a.pk = b.pk
 WHERE b.rn = 1
```